# Spring Aop ProxyFactoryBean and ProxyFactory and ClassCastException

Tags: spring, spring-aop, proxyfactory

When i use `ProxyFactoryBean` to get proxy object, I get a **ClassCastException**，but when i use ProxyFactory's `getProxy()` to get a proxy object, it works properly. I use Spring 4.x.

Definition of Two Beans，WaiterTest and Seller:

```
public class WaiterTest {
    public void greetTo(String name){
        System.out.println("waiter greet to " + name +"...");
    }
    public void serveTo(String name){
        System.out.println("waiter serving " + name + "...");
    }
}

public class Seller {
    public void greetTo(String name){
        System.out.println("seller greet to " +name + "...");
    }
}
```

Definition of Advice：

```
public class GreetingBeforeAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice{

    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object obj) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + "." + method.getName());
        String clientName =(String) args[0];
        System.out.println("How are you! Mr." + clientName +".");
    }
}
```

Definition of Advisor：

```
public class GreetingAdvisor extends StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor {
    public boolean matches(Method method, Class clazz) {
        return "greetTo".equals(method.getName());
    }

    public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
        return new ClassFilter() {
            public boolean matches(Class clazz) {
                return WaiterTest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Test Class：

```
   public class TestGreetingBeforeAdvisor {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //method one：  use by ProxyFactory
            WaiterTest targetWaiterTest = new WaiterTest();
            Seller targetSeller = new Seller();

            GreetingBeforeAdvice advice = new GreetingBeforeAdvice();
            GreetingAdvisor advisor = new GreetingAdvisor();
            advisor.setAdvice(advice);

            ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory();
            pf.setTarget(targetWaiterTest);
            pf.addAdvisor(advisor);
            pf.setOptimize(true);
            WaiterTest proxy = (WaiterTest) pf.getProxy();
            proxy.greetTo("John");
            proxy.serveTo("Tom");

            ProxyFactory pf1 = new ProxyFactory();
            pf1.setTarget(targetSeller);
            pf1.addAdvisor(advisor);
            Seller seller = (Seller) pf1.getProxy();
            seller.greetTo("John"); 
            System.out.println("=============");


            //method two：Spring xml，use ProxyFactoryBean
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
                 WaiterTest test = (WaiterTest) ctx.getBean("waiterTest");
        test .greetTo("John");
        test .serveTo("John");
    }
 }
```

Beans.xml：

```
<bean id="waiterTarget" class="com.xxx.springaop.advisor.WaiterTest"/>
    <bean id="sellerTarget" class="com.xxx.springaop.advisor.Seller"/>
    <bean id="greetingAdvice1" class="com.xxx.springaop.advisor.GreetingBeforeAdvice"/>
    <bean id="greetingAdvisor" class="com.xxx.springaop.advisor.GreetingAdvisor"
        p:advice-ref="greetingAdvice1"/>
    <bean id="parent" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
        p:interceptorNames="greetingAdvisor" 
        p:proxyTargetClass="true"/>

    <bean id="waiterTest" parent="parent" p:target-ref="waiterTarget"/>
    <bean id="seller" parent="parent" p:target-ref="sellerTarget"/>
```

result:

```
com.xxx.springaop.advisor.WaiterTest.greetTo
How are you! Mr.John.
waiter greet to John...
waiter serving Tom...
seller greet to John...
=============
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 cannot be cast to com.xxx.springaop.advisor.WaiterTest
    at com.xxx.springaop.advisor.TestGreetingBeforeAdvisor.main(TestGreetingBeforeAdvisor.java:48)
```

Summarize：

```
WaiterTest proxy = (WaiterTest) pf.getProxy(); //success
WaiterTest test = (WaiterTest) ctx.getBean("waiterTest");//fail,ClassCastException
```

Why?

Comment: For me everything seems to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your problem, but I did some refactoring on your code, and this works just fine for me. Maybe it helps you as well at least as a starting point..

**Waiter.java**

```
public class Waiter {
    public void greetTo(String name) {
        System.out.println("waiter greet to " + name + "...");
    }

    public void serveTo(String name) {
        System.out.println("waiter serving " + name + "...");
    }
}
```

**GreetingBeforeAdvice.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class GreetingBeforeAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice {

    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object obj) throws Throwable {
        String clientName = (String) args[0];
        System.out.println("How are you! Mr." + clientName + ".");
    }
}
```

**GreetingAdvisor.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.ClassFilter;
import org.springframework.aop.support.StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class GreetingAdvisor extends StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor {

    public boolean matches(Method method, Class clazz) {
        return "greetTo".equals(method.getName());
    }

    public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
        return new ClassFilter() {
            public boolean matches(Class clazz) {
                return Waiter.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="waiter" class="Waiter"/>

    <!-- Advisor Configuration -->
    <bean id="greetingAdvice" class="GreetingBeforeAdvice"/>
    <bean id="greetingAdvisor" class="GreetingAdvisor">
        <property name="advice" ref="greetingAdvice"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="waiterProxyFactory" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>greetingAdvisor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="target" ref="waiter"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and finally **App.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        final Waiter waiter = (Waiter) ctx.getBean("waiterProxyFactory");
        waiter.greetTo("Koray Tugay");
        waiter.serveTo("Koray Tugay");
    }
}
```

The output for me is as follows using Spring 4.3.12:

```
How are you! Mr.Koray Tugay.
waiter greet to Koray Tugay...
waiter serving Koray Tugay...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have not configured 'target' object in you ProxyFactoryBean definition. A proxy cannot be created if it does not have a target.